# AppCompat v21 Spinner Styles

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-appcompat, material-design

I just brought my AppCompat v20 app up to API 21, along with AppCompat v21. Most things came forward with no issues, and this article helped: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/ I have most views looking OK except for Spinners. My App's theme is:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I have no custom styles defined for spinners.  I also have no layouts defined, I add the spinners programmatically to the views. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

I also have MinSdkVersion set to 15. Some styles are obviously from the new Material theme, like the dark EditText line, but my custom text style for labels and text seems to be the same as it was, so it migrated OK. What can I do to get my spinner styled like the rest of the theme? It seems that something in AppCompat v21 thinks I'm on a Dark theme when My theme is light.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm still seeing it too.

Comment: @Silver Sort of. It's an incomplete Support Library on Google's part. I'll add my answer that is a decent workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this for now, until the API 21 AppCompat and Support Library gets a bit more flushed out. What you have to do is create an xml layout for your spinner:
     
    
    
Then in your code:

```
final View spinView = inflate(context, R.layout.mult_choice, null);
spin = (Spinner) spinView.findViewById(R.id.mult_choice_spinner);
addView(spin);
```

And it will pickup proper styles from your theme.

Comment: Might give it a go. I went the other way and simply used the Lollipop spinner for api-21+ and defaulted to the Holo spinner for anything older